# What is the default styling for html in components like JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Swing has a nice feature where some components allow text to be specified using html.  For example, the JLabel component can use html formatting simply using:

```java
JLabel jl = new JLabel("<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>");
```

I find this feature to be really convenient and I am using it in several places in my app.

I would like to know what the default styling is when I use this feature.  I know that I can easily override these by adding my own style attributes, but I would like to know what the starting set is, because it is different than most browser defaults.

**Where can I find out the default styling (font, line spacing, etc)?**  I have not seen anything in the documentation.  I tried to browse through the source code, but I was unable to see where the  tag gets parsed and the styling gets applied.

Can someone give me a pointer as to where to look for this information, possibly in the OpenJDK source?

Answer (score 1):

The default style sheet is [`default.css`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/text/html/default.css), which can be found in `resources.jar` under the directory `javax/swing/text/html/default.css`.

You can also obtain the styles programmatically:

```
StyleSheet sheet = new HTMLEditorKit().getStyleSheet();
```

Comment: I found resources.jar file in the jdk-1.8/jre/lib directory, but I can't find it in the jdk-11 folder.  has it been moved?

Comment: I don't think that this has the defaults for using html within JLabel.  For example, defaults.css contains this:body  {font-size: 14pt;
       font-family: Serif;
       font-weight: normal;
       margin-left: 0;
       margin-right: 0;
       color: black}          but the html text in the JLabel shows up as a sans-serif font

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first answer is correct but incomplete.
Check out `SwingUtilities2.displayPropertiesToCSS()`.
It adds a rule to the document stylesheet based on the component's font and foreground color. It is used by `BasicHTML.BasicDocument`.